# Декораторы event и command в discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Возникла вот такая проблема в процессе написания бота для дискорда на Python. Написал функцию, чтобы при отправлении сообщения производились какие-то действия с базой данных. Вот сама функция с соответствующим декоратором:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    #действия с бд
```

Но при использовании данной функции у меня перестают работать команды. Вот сама команда (самая простая):

```
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.send(f"Hello, {author.mention}!")
```

Не могу понять в чём проблема. Может есть какой-то другой декоратор, позволяющий производить какие-то действия при отправке сообщений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[F.A.Q./Why does on_message make my commands stop working?](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.1/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working):

> Замена стандартного `on_message` предотвращает выполнение любых дополнительных команд. Для исправления этого добавьте добавьте строку `bot.process_commands(message)` в конце вашего `on_message`, например:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # делаем что-нибудь тут

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```